# how to upload images in array and remove them

Tags: angularjs, arrays, ng-file-upload

I need to upload multiple images  using multiple , but I need to display name of the file instantly down as a tag , I need to move the files in array. But I am able to fetch only one file name.

http://plnkr.co/edit/BSvgdTms8iu2TKekdgtJ?p=preview

```
JS: 
(function (module) {

var fileReader = function ($q, $log) {

    var onLoad = function(reader, deferred, scope) {
        return function () {
            scope.$apply(function () {
                deferred.resolve(reader.result);
            });
        };
    };

    var onError = function (reader, deferred, scope) {
        return function () {
            scope.$apply(function () {
                deferred.reject(reader.result);
            });
        };
    };

    var onProgress = function(reader, scope) {
        return function (event) {
            scope.$broadcast("fileProgress",
                {
                    total: event.total,
                    loaded: event.loaded
                });
        };
    };

    var getReader = function(deferred, scope) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = onLoad(reader, deferred, scope);
        reader.onerror = onError(reader, deferred, scope);
        reader.onprogress = onProgress(reader, scope);
        return reader;
    };

    var readAsDataURL = function (file, scope) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        var reader = getReader(deferred, scope);         
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    return {
        readAsDataUrl: readAsDataURL  
    };
};
     module.factory("fileReader",
                   ["$q", "$log", fileReader]);
 }());
```

My code is present in plunker link provided. I need only one image preview, but all file names to be displayed below. And once uploaded , the images should be stored in array format.

Comment: You have a wrong tag `ng-file-upload` here. You are not using `ng-file-upload`

Comment: I dont understand your statement.

Comment: You have tagged this question with `ng-file-upload` which means that it is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-file-upload but it is not so remove the tag please.